# Is it possible to embed an Outlook .msg into an application using OLE?

Tags: winapi, outlook, com, ms-office, ole

If you have some application with an ordinary `HWND`, is it possible to embed an Outlook email `.msg` file into the window using `OLE`?

It appears that, after opening an Outlook message using `OpenSharedItem`, you can successfully `QueryInterface` for `IOleObject`.  But after that, I can't seem to successfully call any `IOleObject` methods.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: To display an Outlook .msg preview. But I'd like to avoid parsing it with `MAPI` if possible.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, MSG file format is well-described in MSDN. There is no need to parse it with MAPI.

Answer (score 0):

[MSG file format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxmsg/b046868c-9fbf-41ae-9ffb-8de2bd4eec82) is well-described in MSDN. So, you can read the content without any third-party components or interfaces. To display the content (I guess the message body) you can use any web browser (for example, WebView2). The message body (HTMLBody) is represented by a regular web page. Most probably you will also need attached files that are used in the body.

Another possible alternative to use Extended MAPI for getting item properties. For example, you can use any third-party components for simplifying the work - Redemption.

Comment: *"So, you can read the content without any third-party components or interfaces."* - I doubt that's accurate. The specification is 38 pages, and that's not even including the [CFB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cfb/53989ce4-7b05-4f8d-829b-d08d6148375b) (which weighs in at another 46 pages). While you *can* implement both protocols, it's absolutely not something you want to do. Either one is littered with tens and hundreds of opportunities to get just a tiny detail wrong. Don't expect to get a robust parser in anything less than 3 months.

Comment: Another alternative without so much detailed documentation is to use Extended MAPI which I also mentioned in the post. For example, you can use Redemption to get the code running in less than an hour!